# Looking for a payout script or software

Tags: baking, bakery, payment

I am solo-baker running a node. I want evolve to small bakery. I am looking for a simple script or software that will automate payouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a brand new tool called [Gingerbread](https://medium.com/zednode/introducing-gingerbread-ae61644d3bb6), which the link describes as:

> an open source dashboard application that makes it easier for bakers to track rewards and payout their delegators.

Answer (score 5):

[Tezos Reward Distributor](https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-reward-distributor) is a great solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few choices that I know of:

- [Tezos Reward Distributor](https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-reward-distributor)
- [Backerei](https://github.com/cryptiumlabs/backerei)
- [TAPS](https://medium.com/coinmonks/installing-tezos-taps-382adedd6a0f)

You be the judge.

Also be aware that it is likely in the not so far off future, on-chain reward mechanisms will be able to built via smart contracts which may be a good supplement and/or replacement for the above options. This protocol upgrade proposal is described more in Cryptium Labs' Medium [article](https://medium.com/cryptium/introducing-the-burebrot-protocol-upgrade-beebf202353a).